# How to type the dot in github markdown list?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I try to use the markdown format to write a list in my readme file.

But in [the github flavoured markdown](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#wiki-lists), it using a dot `"⋅"`  not period(`"."`) to indicate the align for list.

How to type such dot from regular US/English keyboard? I tried to copy and paste to github, it's not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried * (asterisk) your points? Those "dots" in that link is just spaces. They put that in the manual so you can visualize the spaces, not that it is a literal "dot" character.

Like:

- This is a point

  - This is a subpoint
- this is another point.

  - This is another subpoint

What they mean is:

1. First ordered list item
2. Another item

   - Unordered sub-list.
3. Actual numbers don't matter, just that it's a number

   1. Ordered sub-list
4. And another item.

   You can have properly indented paragraphs within list items. Notice the blank line above, and the leading spaces (at least one, but we'll use three here to also align the raw Markdown).

   To have a line break without a paragraph, you will need to use two trailing spaces.⋅⋅
   Note that this line is separate, but within the same paragraph.⋅⋅
   (This is contrary to the typical GFM line break behaviour, where trailing spaces are not required.)

   - Unordered list can use asterisks
   - Or minuses
   - Or pluses

Here's the raw code:

```
1. First ordered list item
2. Another item
  * Unordered sub-list. 
1. Actual numbers don't matter, just that it's a number
  1. Ordered sub-list
4. And another item.

   You can have properly indented paragraphs within list items. Notice the blank line above, and the leading spaces (at least one, but we'll use three here to also align the raw Markdown).

   To have a line break without a paragraph, you will need to use two trailing spaces.⋅⋅
   Note that this line is separate, but within the same paragraph.⋅⋅
   (This is contrary to the typical GFM line break behaviour, where trailing spaces are not required.)

* Unordered list can use asterisks
- Or minuses
+ Or pluses
```

Comment: This is work, but I would like to use that specific style without any dot or number in front of points.

Answer (score 2):

Just hit space multiple spaces for soft-breaks;
(·) was just for notation

[try this lesson Here](http://www.markdowntutorial.com/lesson/7/)